# Converting assembly code to machine code in C manually

Tags: c, assembly

I've been given a practise homework to do from college which requires me to manually convert assembly code to machine code. I will display the images of what the before and after looks like. It basically requires my to remove the comments (after semi colon) and white spaces after the instruction. I found this to be puzzling since im a C noob and ive been thrown into assembly code. I am planning to do this in notepad++. The assembly language im using is meant to be very simplified since x86 would be ridiculous to start off on. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Am glad am not in your college.

Comment: You are not converting anything to machine code, you are just being asked to strip comments and whitespace. Assembly is purely incidental in this exercise, which boils down to dumb string manipulation.

Comment: Posting text as images is against site-rules. Post text as text!

Comment: What the hell is that assignment supposed to teach you?  The hardest part is probably learning how to submit an assignment...  See the [assembly tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info) for links when your course gets to the point of talking about what assembly language does, rather than just how the lines are formatted.

Comment: yh sorry guys thats my bad because this was the start of the assignment. I go on to converting the code like mov goes to 0x01 etc...

Comment: Oh, I missed that you had to write a C program to do this.  That contradicts the "manually".  So it's a decent string-parsing C assignment.  If you have to output machine code based on a lookup table for opcodes and operands, then you're writing an assembler, which simply assembles bytes into an output file (according to a text description) like any other assembler.  The asm tag wiki might still be useful to help you grok that concept.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment, this has nothing to do with machine code, it's just trivial string manipulation (essentially, it's `sed 's/[[:space:]]*\(;.*\)\?$//'`):

1. Read a line
2. Walk the string one character at time; each time you find a non-whitespace character, write down its position in a variable.
3. When you find either the end of the string (character 0) or a semicolon (character `';'`), truncate the string to the character following the last non-whitespace one you found (effectively, set it to zero).
4. Write down the updated string to the other file.
5. Repeat until the input file is finished.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand why you would use sed in notepad++ since its for linux? surely its not as trivial as it look as first you have to read each line using fgets and then somehow get rid of the whitespaces and comments. Unfortunately i don't understand how i could do this with regular C code like fread etc...

Comment: I assume i may need to use isspace to check for white spaces

Comment: @Jim: the `sed` part is just an example to show you that this is a trivial text manipulation that can be done with a simple regex (you can surely do that in Notepad++ from the search/replace dialog, probably its regex syntax is more Perl-like, I expect something like replace `\s*(;.*)?$` with nothing). Anyway, the points 1 to 5 are the algorithm you have to implement in C (step 4 is not required if you don't actually need to write the result on another file), each point is fairly trivial.